# Finding errors in several folders full of logfiles powershell script

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I want to find "error" in log files. There is time and date on every folder. you can see down below how it looks like. Inside of these folder there is other folder that are named "mail1" "mail2" on so on. The logfiles are inside the mail1, mail2, mail3 and so on. The path to one of the log files is c:\2019-05-24 00.00.09\mail1\mail.log

```
2019-05-24 00.00.09

2019-05-23 00.00.08

2019-05-22 00.00.05

2019-05-21 00.00.06

2019-05-20 00.00.09
```

My example just showed for finding error in 1 log file.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\123\Desktop\log\mail.log | Select-Object -first 10000 | Select-String ("Error") | Out-file C:\Users\1234\Desktop\leave\ouputerror.txt
```

can someone pls give me an easy example on how to find errors in several folders full of logfile.

Comment: What is a mapp?

Comment: sorry, i mean folder. I just edited my post

Comment: your tell me the location of the error is something like `C:\2019-05-24 00.00.09\Mail1\mail.log` ?

Comment: Yes thats the log from one the path to the log

Comment: Please edit the question again and change the `mapp` to `folder` in the title too. Also, your example code does not show anything of the folder structure as described (no time and date folder names anywhere). Show a relevant part of the real structure.

Comment: you missed the answer Theo, sorry, i mean folder. I just edited my post – Hello123 2 days ago. Pls read it correctly. i gave an example of 1 log file.  "My example just showed for finding error in 1 log file."

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your `2019-05-24 00.00.09` folders are located in `C:\LogFolder`. Then you can use something like this.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\LogFolder -Recurse -Filter *.log | ForEach-Object { Get-content $_.Fullname | Select-Object -first 10000 | Select-String ("Error") } | Out-file C:\Users\1234\Desktop\leave\ouputerror.txt -Append
```

Comment: I had tested my code so i know it works. So now the reason it doesn't work for you would be either (1) There are no "error" strings in your log files or (2) You are not giving the correct log folder. See if `Get-ChildItem C:\LogFolder -Recurse -Filter *.log` returns anything. Change `C:\logfolder` to appropriate path in your computer.

Comment: it doesnt return anything. nothing wrong with the path and there is errors in my log file. I have Powershell v1.0. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Nvm, it was something on my computer that blocked it. Thank you for helping.